# How to return to the previous screen in flutter when using persistent_bottom_nav_bar package?

Tags: flutter, navigation, back-button

I have searched the package docs to return just to the previous screen & didn't find a simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```